# Kentico 10 export site ambiguous columns

Tags: kentico

I am trying to export a site in Kentico 10.  During the export Pages section, a page template I created fails with the following error message.

```
Message: Ambiguous column name 'City'.
Ambiguous column name 'State'.
Ambiguous column name 'PostalCode'.
```

These are pretty common fields.  Do I need to do something special to my page type?

Comment: In your export page section any pagetype or custom table having same field name ? Can you provide some more information so I can try to figure out  the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this columns are in your custom page types, but this is not an issue that you have the same column names. Issue can be in that definition of specific column is different in those page types. For exmaple: on one page type is defined as text (varchar) and on the second page type is int (integer)

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I didn't realize they needed to be the same type.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, or you need to name the fields in unique way, otherwise you may face this error too: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/conversion-failed-when-converting-from-a-character-string-to-uniqueidentifier